# Why auto is deduced differently?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference

```
int main(){
    int x{};
    auto x2 = x;
    auto x3{x};

    static_assert(is_same<int, decltype(x)>::value, "decltype(x) is the same as int");
    static_assert(is_same<int, decltype(x2)>::value, "decltype(x2) is the same as int");
    static_assert(is_same<int, decltype(x3)>::value, "decltype(x3) is the same as int"); // Error here.
}
```

This codes does not compile with gcc 4.8.0.
I don't even guess the type of `decltype(x3)`. What is it? And why the behavior is different?

Comment: declaration errors....

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan could you be more specific?

Comment: `auto x{y}` is an `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: x3 is actually deduced as an `initializer_list<int>`.

Comment: @Xeo: Ok, I see. So I cannot use brace-initialization syntax for auto right?

Comment: @Sungmin I don't know c++11 that why I didn't add answer, but as I understand you have declaration errors. Sorry :(

Comment: @Sungmin: Correct. Well, you can, but it won't be the result you want.

Comment: i think int x{}; wont even compile or am i missing something?!

Comment: Hmm, this is maybe very stupid question. Sorry for the noise.. I had to study more.

Comment: Do you mean it's failing because of the static assert involving `x3`? Or is there some other error?

Comment: @sungmin sure you can, it you want an `initializer_list`. :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Yes. because of the static_assert.

Comment: @ZoomIn: `int x{};` is fine, it value-initialises `x` as an `int`.

Comment: @Sungmin I don't this was a bad question at all and clearly a lot of the SO community agrees

Comment: @Mankarse thanks,but i didnt get it compiling on visual studio 2012(c++ 11) compiler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x{};
    auto x2 = x;
    auto x3{x};

    static_assert(is_same<int, decltype(x)>::value, "decltype(x) is the same as int");
    static_assert(is_same<int, decltype(x2)>::value, "decltype(x2) is the same as int");
    static_assert(is_same<std::initializer_list<int>, decltype(x3)>::value, "decltype(x3) is the same as int");
}
```

This will compile. `x3` is deduced to be a `std::initializer_list<int>` due to:

> Let `T` be the type that has been determined for a variable identifier `d`. Obtain `P` from T [...] if the initializer is a braced-init-list (8.5.4), with `std::initializer_list<U>`.

Answer (score 6):

So `x3` is actually an `std::initializer_list<int>`, one way for you to have figured this out would be as follows:

```
std::cout << typeid(x3).name() << std::endl ;
```

for me I had the following output:

```
St16initializer_listIiE
```

Putting this through `c++filt`:

```
c++filt -t St16initializer_listIiE
```

Gives me:

```
std::initializer_list<int>
```